# How to change text in Toggle switch from NuGet?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using a [Toggle switch](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ToggleSwitch) that I downloaded from NuGet.

It has a standard "ON/OFF" text on the switch.

[image]
[image]

I was trying to change the text to say something else, is this possible through styles on XAML?

Comment: Looking through the source code there seems to be a `CheckedContent` property that can be bound to as well as a `UncheckedContent`.

Comment: @DavidPilkington, that is were I am getting unstuck, I am guessing you `ControlTemplate` to change this, but I don't know what I am trying to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems the answer was so simple I am really surprised,

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type switch:HorizontalToggleSwitch}">
      <Setter Property="CheckedContent" Value="RUN"/>
      <Setter Property="UncheckedContent" Value="STOP"/>
</Style>
```

This changes the text value for each state.

Answer (score 4):

As @DavidPilkington mentioned, use the `CheckedContent` and `UncheckedContent` properties. They accept "content" just like a `Button` or any other `ContentControl`, meaning you can assign simple text to them:

```
<toggleSwitch:HorizontalToggleSwitch IsChecked="True" CheckedContent="Activated!" />
```

or anything inheriting from `UIElement`:

```
<toggleSwitch:HorizontalToggleSwitch>
    <toggleSwitch:HorizontalToggleSwitch.UncheckedContent>
        <StackPanel>
            <Ellipse Height="40" Width="40" Fill="Blue"/>
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center">Disabled</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </toggleSwitch:HorizontalToggleSwitch.UncheckedContent>
</toggleSwitch:HorizontalToggleSwitch>
```

Comment: Up vote for the help and your answer helped me get to my answer.