# VBA If/Then with ActiveCell issue

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I'm receiving an error with my VBA and don't understand why:

I'm trying to make a MsgBox appear when the activecell in the active workbook does not meet a criteria.

here's my short line of code:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveCell <> ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" Then MsgBox "Please Enter a Date"
```

The error I receive is:

```
Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method.
```

Does anyone have an idea about why this would happen?

**EDIT:**

Currently we have a macro in our workbooks that automatically records the time NOW() when an analyst clicks an empty cell. They can go back and change this date (because sometimes they need to), but sometimes they forget to add in the MM/DD/YYYY format, and just have hh:mm:ss, which doesn't help when we're trying use these cells to subtract from different dates. I want the analyst to be required to make sure the cell they just changed is in the format 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'

SAMPLE:
Here's some sample code I have so far:

```
    Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
'
' TimeStamp Macro
'
Dim AutoTime
    AutoTime = True  'set to False to stop auto date/time insertion on mouse click

    If (AutoTime And ActiveCell = "" And ActiveCell.Column > 6 And ActiveCell.Column < 17 And ActiveCell.Row > 3) Then
         ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"
         Selection.Copy
         Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
         Selection.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
    End Sub
```

Which someone I work with provided. What this does it enters in NOW() to an active cell when an analyst clicks it, if the cell is blank.

So,

```
G                       H                    I
1/5/2017
```

Becomes,

```
G                       H                    I
1/5/2017      1/5/2017 09:30:00 A.M.
```

Now the analyst can again click I, and the cell will return NOW().

The issue:

Sometimes analyst change these times, especially when the NOW() function wasn't needed. What they don't do is include the '1/5/2017 ' in front, so now I have

```
G                       H                         I
1/5/2017      1/5/2017 09:30:00 A.M.        10:45:00 A.M.
```

I want a message box to appear when any of the cells in my range that they changed manually doesn't include 'mm/dd/yyyy' because excel doesn't like I1 - H1

Comment: Your Boolean expression is incredibly hard to parse, *if* it's valid at all. And if it's valid, it probably doesn't evaluate to what you think it should. The answer below is making an assumption as to exactly what your condition is trying to evaluate.

Comment: Ill add some more detail

Comment: Why does the format of the cell impact a subtraction?  The format is just saying how it should be **displayed**, not what the underlying number in the cell is.  It sounds more like that they have just entered the time, and not the date and time.

Comment: In Excel Cell Numberformats are case sensitive, there's no such format as `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS` whereas `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` is a valid format.

Comment: Because when an analyst enters in their generic time 09:36:15 A.M. I believe excel interprets this as the year 1900. I have 6-7 cells that have times in them, from left to right increasing in date/time, I'm subtracting the differences of each cell, so if cell A1 is '9:30:14 am' and cell B1 is '1/5/2017 10:45:15 A.M.', when I am determining the difference it is causing errors

Comment: Cell A1 should always have a date accompanied with the time, so it should say '1/5/2017 9:36:15 A.M.'

Comment: @cyboashu - is that only in Excel itself?  VBA allows `"MM/DD/YYYY"` or `"mm/dd/yyyy"` when setting the `NumberFormat`.

Comment: So the issue is not the format of the cell, but that `ActiveCell.Value2 < 1`

Comment: @YowE3K run this Application.ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
?Application.ActiveCell.NumberFormat you will never get back "MM/DD/YYYY" instead
mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: @cyboashu - Yes, it is case insensitive - so the users can "add in the MM/DD/YYYY format" **or** "mm/dd/yyyy" format - both are equally valid.  The only place where case sensitivity would be a concern is if the set value was being checked within VBA, and the OP was correctly checking for a lower-cased version.

Comment: yeah, you are 100% right :)

Comment: @cyboashu - I am **always** right!!  (Except when my wife tells me that I'm wrong. :(  )

Comment: hahaha.... good one :)

Answer (score 4):

Because there is no ActiveCell property inside ActiveWorkbook.

ActiveCell is application property and it will be always on the ActiveWorkbook.

```
  If Not IsDate(ActiveCell) Or ActiveCell.NumberFormat <> "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" Then
        MsgBox "Enter date!"
    End If
```

---

To check if the ActiveCell contains a Valide Date +Time and not 1900 as date :

```
Sub TEST()

    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
        If Not Application.Evaluate("=AND(YEAR(" & ActiveCell.Value2 & ") >=2016,MOD(" & ActiveCell.Value2 & ",2))") Then
            MsgBox "Not a valid date time!!"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Any date before the year 2016 will be flagged. so will any entry with just date and no time.

Comment: This resolve the issue I had with the error, but it's not working properly. The actual format of the cells is hh:mm:ss, but the underlying number is mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss. This may be causing an issue, because the format is "custom" not date, and MsgBox appears on any cell, even when they are in mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss format

Comment: format is "custom" not date , wht do you mean by that? For dates (and times or both ) underlying values are always numbers, nothing else, just numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking your line down into its components

```
If ActiveWorkbook.ActiveCell <> ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" Then MsgBox "Please Enter a Date"
```

The first thing that Excel does is look for the `ActiveCell` property of the `ActiveWorkbook` object.  That property doesn't exist, so you get your error.

But let's pretend it does (and that you had just used `ActiveCell`), then the second thing that happens is that it compares `ActiveCell`'s default `Value` property with `ActiveCell`'s `NumberFormat` property.  Those two values are unlikely to be the same, so a test for `<>` will be `True`.

Next, a comparison of `True` is made with the string "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss".  Even if you don't get a "type mismatch" error, that would return a `False`.

---

Based on your comments to the question, what you want is:

```
If ActiveCell.Value2 < 1 Then MsgBox "Please Enter a Date"
```

How the cell is formatted should not impact on whether the date is valid or not, it only affects how the cell's value is **displayed**.

---

The functionality to test for the validity of entered values needs to go into the `Change` event rather than the `SelectionChange` event, so I would recommend changing your code to:

```
Option Explicit
Private Const AutoTime As Boolean = True 'set to False to stop auto date/time insertion on mouse click

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not AutoTime Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Target
        If c.Value <> "" And c.Column > 6 And c.Column < 17 And c.Row > 3 Then
            If Not IsNumeric(c.Value2) Then
                MsgBox "Cell " & c.Address & " - Please enter a valid date/time"
            ElseIf c.Value2 < 1 Then
                MsgBox "Cell " & c.Address & " - Please enter the date as well as the time"
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'
' TimeStamp Macro
'
    If Not AutoTime Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Target
        If c.Value = "" And c.Column > 6 And c.Column < 17 And c.Row > 3 Then
            c.Value = Now()
            c.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be doing what I expect either. I apologize for the confusion... I will include a sample

Comment: Based on your example data, column I contains `0.447916666666667` so `ActiveCell.Value2` will be less than 1, therefore the `MsgBox` should be displayed.

Comment: I am upvoting this answer , there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @KyloRen - thanks - I hadn't even noticed that it had been downvoted until you said something  :D

Comment: @YowE3K, someone really did not like that, they revenge voted a question I asked and answered on my own. LOL .People are so petty sometimes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463885/how-to-change-text-in-toggle-switch-from-nuget/41476823#41476823

Comment: @KyloRen Luckily for me, my (suspected) Asperger's means I don't understand how other people think, but I don't care whether they like me or not anyway.  (And I certainly don't want to get too high a rep score or else people will start expecting me to have all the answers, and I wouldn't be able to cope with that.)

Comment: what's this gobblygook? what happens when active cell is something like `1/1/0000 10:10:10`? Is it a date? Yes As per IsDate ? What about Value2? Value2 < 1 returns false. Guess what Typename(Activecell.value2) is string. This code is so wrong and misleading. If OP's users can forget date part then they can certainly put in wrong date too.

Comment: `How the cell is formatted should not impact on whether the date is valid or not.`  Oh yes, it certainly does. Guess  what's value2 when the format is `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` and date entered is  `14/1/2014  10:10:10 AM`. Its once again string. so the ActiveCell.Value2 < 1 means false. means whole premise fails, once again.

Comment: @YowE3K do  a favor to the community and delete this answer. Its just wrong.

Comment: @teddy2 - When the active cell is something like `1/1/0000 10:10:10` (i.e. an invalid date) then the `Value2` property will return the same as the `Value` property, i.e. the text string entered.  Although `IsDate` will decide that it could be converted to a date (due to Y2K windowing), Excel would continue to have issues with it, so the OP would not want that date to be accepted, despite `IsDate` being happy with it.  However, the OP has stated that the users are not entering incorrect dates, just times without dates, so it's really not the issue affecting this question.

Comment: @teddy2 - when a cell is formatted as `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` and the date entered is `14/1/2014 10:10:10 AM` then `Value2` will return `"14/1/2014 10:10:10 AM"` if your local date format is `mm/dd/yyyy` (because that's not a valid date in that locale) or `41653.4237268519` if your local date format is `dd/mm/yyyy` (because that is a valid date in that locale).  The answer is not affected by the cell format, simply by whether a valid date/time was entered.

Comment: @teddy2 - The important thing in this question is that the users are just entering a (valid) time, which Excel will store as being on 1 Jan 1900, and will have a `Value2` property between 0 and 0.9999999.

Comment: @teddy2, are you really saying that the formating affects if a date is valid or not? I think you need to go back and do a bit more study.

Comment: I like the way you did this, and it works, mostly, but I am testing this, and I can change the cell to remove the date that the now() function replaces and nothing happens whenever I click on a different cell. Only until I go back and click on the cell I know has no date do I get the MsgBox "Please enter a date!!"

Comment: @DukeLuke - Ahh - of course - you were working in the `SelectionChange` event, but the functionality to test for valid values needs to go into the `Change` event.  I've updated the answer.